# PHP: Pass file into script as stdin

Tags: php, pipe, stdin, php-7

I am attempting to write some tests for an email parser I am building and having trouble getting started.

For normal operation an email will be piped to the script, but for the tests I want to simulate the piping action : )

My test is starting out like this:

```
#!/opt/php70/bin/php
<?php

define('INC_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));

$script = INC_ROOT . '/app/email_parser.php';

//$email = file_get_contents(INC_ROOT . '/tests/test_emails/test.email');
$email = INC_ROOT . '/tests/test_emails/test.email';

passthru("{$script}<<<{$email}");
```

With the script as is, the only thing passed to stdin is the path to the test email. When using file_get_contents I get:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('
sh: -c: line 0: /myscriptpath/app/email_parser.php<<<TestEmailContents
```

Where TestEmailContents is the contents of the raw email file. I feel like I have executed scripts in this manner in the past using the heredoc operator to pass data into stdin. But for the last few days I have been unable to find any information to get me past this stumbling block. Any advice will be mucho appreciado!

Comment: It looks like redirecting with the heredoc operator (<<<) is not necessary when executing the script. Am having better luck with the single redirect operator (<).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error experienced was exactly that. To get the file contents and pass it in as a here string I needed to single quote the string:

```
$email = file_get_contents(INC_ROOT . '/tests/test_emails/test.email');

passthru("{$script} <<< '{$email}'");
```

But, in my case passing in a raw email did not require the use of a here string. The line endings are preserved either way. Redirecting the file to the script yielded the same results.

```
$email = INC_ROOT . '/tests/test_emails/test.email';

passthru("{$script} < {$email}");
```

Comment: very interesting.  Found your thread because i need to do the same thing.  I have a script that parses incoming emails and it works fine - I don't want to touch it.  However I want to write another script that reads all files from a certain Inbox and passes each file/email to the parsing script to go through all the past emails (that came in before the parsing script was implemented).    I know this is old, but any chance you still have the final solution?

Comment: I used both methods above and in both cases the raw emails being processed did so cleanly 50% of the time, the other 50% I got errors similar to your OP.  Someone suggested doing `base64_encode(file_get_contents('emailFile'))` and that eliminated all the errors, however it also caused a problem with my parsing script failing explode the STDIN into individual lines - instead of 200+ lines per email to loop through, each email was now two lines, and as a result nothing was captured.

Comment: Correction!  Your second one, `passthru("{$script} < {$email}") ;` worked just fine, turns out my `$email` had a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

To read stdin in PHP you can use `php://stdin` filename: `$content = file_get_contents('php://stdin');` or `$f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');`.

To pass a string to an invoked process you have two options: [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). The `popen` function is easier to use, but it has limited use. The `proc_open` is a bit more complicated, but gives you much finer control of stdio redirection.

Both function give you file handle(s) on which you can use `fwrite` and `fread`. In your case the popen should be good enough (simplified):

```
$f = popen('./script.php', 'w');
fwrite($f, file_get_contents('test.email'));
pclose($f);
```